# Winterbash Hats: localized description

Tags: bug, status-completed, localization, winter-bash-2015

I have visited http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/ to see more about hats

It shows me localized description for hats (Russian). A bit strange after English-only SO.com, I'm Ok with English, but thanks anyway

But some translations hurt because of typos

I did search but couldn't find where I can report it, so I report *here* (meta-stack-overflow originally)

*"Cerro de Potosi" description*

current: заработать серебр**е**ный знак

suggested: заработать серебр**я**ный знак

*"Cerro de Potosi" window*

current: заработайте серебр**е**ный знак

suggested: заработайте серебр**я**ный знак

*"Weed Eater" description*

current: принятый ответ в для Бродяги

suggested: принятый ответ для "Бродяги"

[image: firefox tab]

Edit: before this question was migrated from meta-stack-overflow, it got some explanation in comments:

> the promo site is translated based on the user's browser `Accept-Language` settings
>
> Thomas Orozco

Edit: more issues

"Vote Early, Vote Often", "Fan-hat-ic", "Researcher" descriptions :

current: "к ряду"

suggested: "кряду" or "подряд"

"I’m Batman" description:

current: "закрыт**и**й"

suggested: "закрыт**ы**й"

Comment: Not about [SO] in english, belongs on the [russian Stack Overflow meta](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @Deduplicator, why? announcement is on http://blog.stackoverflow.com/; my question is in English.

Comment: The localized descriptions can only be seen on the localized site, they don't have *anything* to do with *any* non-localized site. You can make a case for posting on [meta.se], though that's weak unless there are more sites localized in that language. As to the blog, that's the company blog-roll, and there's AFAIK no localized version, planned or existing.

Comment: @Deduplicator, i came from main site: SO.com - the only site i have active account

Comment: @Deduplicator Note that the promo site is translated based on the user's `Accept-Language` settings, so assuming ASh's browser is configured to prefer Russian, then ASh gets the Russian version, regardless of which site they came in from.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco: Just seen the update. That makes a strong case to move it to [meta.se] then... And may I say that a site doing something like that always irritates me, though more if the sites don't contain hand-translated the exact same content?

Comment: @Deduplicator This is *a mini-site for an ephemeral event*. Translating the site based on the user's browser language isn't ideal, but it's arguably a decent compromise ; )

Comment: @ThomasOrozco, i could guess it is browser language preference. is it a human or machine translation? should I move it to meta stack exchange or just leave it because it is a *mini-site for an ephemeral event*?

Comment: @ASh It's a human translation by our ru.stackoverflow.com community manager. I'll move it to MSE; you could argue either way where it belongs. Thanks for the fixes, I'll get those in.

Comment: If you want, you can force the descriptions to be in English now: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271394/choose-winter-bash-language/271408#271408

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks for the fixes, I've updated the translations accordingly.

Regarding your general points: We have translated the hat descriptions and the on-site UI (i.e. the hat rack popup etc.) into those languages in which we have sites, which are [Japanese](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/), [Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/), [Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/), and [Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) <s>(currently in private beta)</s>.

The on-site Winter Bash language is based on the site's language, but that doesn't work on [Winter Bash](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/) itself.

The only feasible solution here was to make the language based on whatever your browser requests – if it's one of those four, that's what you get; otherwise you get English.

Myself (native German speaker), I'm not a big fan of half-translated sites, so I do understand your irritation somewhat. But the consensus among our non-English community managers was to still offer it; after all there are now users participating in Winter Bash who may not speak English at all.

Comment: thank you for quick assistance and reply! i have posted only some examples but there are still more typos in other hats:(

Comment: added them to the question, accepted your answer

Comment: Updated. Thanks a lot!