# Spanish translation for Greeter hat is incorrect

Tags: bug, status-completed, localization, winter-bash-2015, spanish-stackoverflow

Recently, I have been having trouble getting the [Greeter hat](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/greeter).

I live in Argentina, so therefore, Stack Exchange sites shows me spanish text when available. This is the case for hat descriptions.

Here is the spanish description for the Greeter hat:

[image: Greeter hat - Spanish]

The translated text would be:

> Upvote another user's first post made during Winter Bash

Pretty easy to accomplish. Yet, I can't manage to get the hat.

So I began to look for solutions, and I stumbled into this question:

[Greeter hat seems to be causing trouble](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312313/greeter-hat-seems-to-be-causing-problems)

Until now I had never read the english description (SE won't let me change the webpage's language, and even if it does, I don't know how), but it goes like this:

> Edit and upvote another user’s first post, which must have been made during Winter Bash

So, there's the magic word! Edit! That was the reason I couldn't win the hat (I hope!)

I don't know if this classifies as a bug, nor do I know how to tag this question (This is my first bug report question), but this needs to be solved if possible.

I'm sure there are a lot of spanish users who may be having the same problem as me due to an incorrect translation of the hat's description.

Comment: Sounds like a localization bug to me. Bug indeed, well spotted! ...and shouldn't "You haven't earned this hat on any sites yet" be translated as well? ...wait, is the translation coming from SE?

Comment: @Mat'sMug It seems that they only translated the hat descriptions, because the rest of the site is in english to me. I suppose it is coming from SE, although I can't say for sure.

Comment: FYI, if you want you can now [disable the translation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271394/choose-winter-bash-language/271408#271408) if you'd rather see the hat descriptions in English.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Why are you removing [tag:spanish-stackoverflow] but not [tag:russian-stackoverflow] and [tag:portuguese-stackoverflow]?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Updated, thanks for pointing that out!

[image: screenshot of the fixed spanish translation of the Greeter hat]

For some general notes on the translation of the Winter Bash site, see my answer here: [Winterbash Hats: localized description](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270845/winterbash-hats-localized-description/270846#270846).

Comment: Thank you! I'm glad it got solved