# Translation for hats

Tags: support, localization, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

Where does the translation for hats in the [Winter Bash page](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/)?

> [image: hats]

I can't find them in transifex.

I see the link in the bottom of the page:

> view hat descriptions in English / translate hat descriptions

but I can't understand where they come from.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Winter Bash doesn't use transifex. The translations to Portuguese, Japanese, Russian, and Spanish are done by the community managers of the respective localized Stack Overflow.

That said, if you notice a typo or something like that, feel free to report that as a bug (it [wouldn't be unprecedented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271238/spanish-translation-for-greeter-hat-is-incorrect)).

Answer (score 15):

Translations for all international sites' hats are done in a special hat-file. You cannot find those strings on Transifex. If you find typo or have any other suggestion for the translation, please, ping an appropriate CM in chat.