# Wrong translation in Portuguese hats

Tags: bug, status-completed, localization, winter-bash-2017

I was trying to get some hats today, and I found something fishy here...
The `I'll Handle It` hat text says this:

> (pt-BR): fechar, editar **ou** reabrir uma pergunta
> (en-US): close, edit **or** reopen a question

<sub>So I edited a question and got nothing... :D</sub>
Then I pressed the `view all text in English` button and voila!

> (en-US): close, edit, reopen a question
> which should be translated to:
> (pt-BR): fechar, editar **e** reabrir uma pergunta <strike>(or just keep the comma there)</strike>

And by the way, shouldn't these titles also be translated?
**Edit**: This observation was answered in the comment section.

#### Wrong hat's description

[image: Failure]

Comment: Related https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288311/339911

Comment: Oh! That makes sense now... Thank you

Comment: I suppose you mean "close, edit or *reopen* a question" (unless there is another mistake so it says "close" twice)

Comment: @DonaldDuck Opps... My bad! Fixed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I pushed the ou -> e change live. Or at least I hit a build that I hope builds production Winterbash. :) Let me know if the old translation is still there.

Comment: Nah, it's fixed. Thank you!