# Choose Winter Bash language

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, languages, winter-bash-2015, winter-bash

For some reason the Winter Bash page is in Spanish. It might be because in my Accept-Language HTTP header Spanish has more priority than English.

But the Spanish page is so confusing for me, because I'm used to the English jargon of SE.

For example, I didn't know that ["tumbleweed"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tumbleweed) in Spanish is ["estepicursor"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estepicursor), because in fact I didn't know what they are. But I knew the [Tumbleweed badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/38/tumbleweed), of course.

[image]

So I want to be able to switch Winter Bash to English. Is there a simple way to do that, without having to alter my Accept-Language?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Tumbleweed argument is a really good point for allowing people to force the hat descriptions to be in English. I've added a way to do that: Scroll down on http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/ and you should now see a link called "view hat descriptions in English", which will disable translations for you. This is a simple cookie-based setting, so you have to do it once per browser if you're accessing the site from multiple machines.

This only applies to http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/ itself; the language on the Q&A site continues to be the one set by the site (in other words, your [hat rack on es.SO](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/1912/oriol#winter-bash) will still show Spanish descriptions, because that's the site's language).