# Translations for hats partially affect opened tab

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, localization, winter-bash-2017

[The Winter Bash 2017](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/) page has ability to show translations for the hat descriptions (link on the page bottom). I noticed that if you open the page twice in different tabs and change the translation mode in one tab it will affect the another tab. In particular you can see a popup with translations on the page where all text is English:

> [image: This is fine]

Is this fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working as [intended](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271394/choose-winter-bash-language/271408#271408):

> This is a simple cookie-based setting

So you're not making the choice to opt out of translations per-page, but per-browser.