# Incomplete localization of the Winter Bash hat popup text translation

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash, localization

The translation of the Winter Bash popup is incomplete on foreign language Stack Overflow sites:

- [https://es.stackoverflow.com/](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/current#winter-bash)
- [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/current#winter-bash)
- [https://ja.stackoverflow.com/](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/current#winter-bash)
- [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/current#winter-bash)

> [image: Winter Bash popup - Stack Overflow Spanish]
> [image: Winter Bash popup - Stack Overflow Portuguese]
> [image: Winter Bash popup - Stack Overflow Japanese]

etc.

Related: ["Winterbash Hats: localized description"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270846/282094)

Comment: Vás a remober tus sombreros Rob :D ?

Comment: @bad_coder Norte.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to learn new languages, okay?? Duolingo only helps so much. Anyways, we've added translations for:

- Japanese
- Portuguese
- Spanish
- Russian

<del>We're currently learning Russian so we can get translations for that deployed (i.e. we're waiting on the translations for Russian)</del>

Update: we've learned Russian.

Comment: We don't have a Spanish-speaking CM any more @Rob. And, yes. We have the translations we do thanks to CMs and other people, we just didn't want to wait on a response from all four before getting something pushed out everywhere.

Comment: Better late than never, but I can't help thinking why you didn't do this *before* winter bash started? (i.e. what was the bug? Or just nobody remembered?)

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars we're only human; we forgot :shrug:

Comment: *Duolingo only helps so much*: try deepl.com, my choice!